# TYPO3 if.isInList not working as expected

Tags: if-statement, typo3, typoscript

I have a simple cObject override which I would like to work if a user is in a certain group. Looking at the TSRef if.isInList should be right for this task? But it doesn't work. This is my snippet:

```
if.isInList.data=TSFE:fe_user|user|usergroup
if.insertData = 1
if.value = 2
```

I tested the override itself with a if.value=1 and if.equals=1 -> works fine. I also checked for the TSFE data by showing it as a string, it has the right usergroup in it and looks like this "3,2" ... also this if works but is not good for me since users can be in many groups and I only want to check for one of them:

```
if.equals.data=TSFE:fe_user|user|usergroup
if.insertData = 1
if.value = 3,2
```

I turned it around and used

```
    if.data=TSFE:fe_user|user|usergroup
    if.insertData = 1
    if.isInList.value = 2
```

... but that will always fire reagrdless of the usergroup

Thanks for any insights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for anyone having the same troubles: 
the syntax must be like this then it will work:

```
   if.value.data=TSFE:fe_user|user|usergroup
   if.isInList = 2
```

Comment: Correctly. ``isInList`` checks whether the given string is in the list of the current data (e.g. provided by ``value``).

Comment: yeah, the tricky part was: inInList accepts a value right away, no need for .value ... somehow I overlooked this all the time ...